# 'bring to the fore" VS "bring to the forefront"

Tags: word-usage

> 1. The acquisition of a large Industrial Hoses manufacturer in Turkey, while “stirring up a hornet’s nest,” **brought to the forefront** Turkish hard work, determination and pride. This results in a smooth and successful transition.
> 2. The acquisition of a large Industrial Hoses manufacturer in Turkey, while “stirring up a hornet’s nest,” **brought to the fore** Turkish hard work, determination and pride. This results in a smooth and successful transition.

My question is whether here **bring to the forefront** means the same thing as **bring to the fore**. 
Is *bring to the forefront* a idiomatic way to say things or a made-up phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forefront is a word, and the expression "bring to the forefront" is quite idiomatic. In fact, it is the example given along with the [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forefront).

> **forefront** - The leading or most important position or place.
>
> *"the issue has moved to the forefront of the political agenda"*

"Forefront" is the very leading position, whereas "fore" means toward the front more generally. Something "brought to the fore" (which is not a very common phrase, at least in the USA) has been brought somewhat toward the front, while something "brought to the forefront" is now at the very front.